# Android screen navigation issue

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation

I get a screen navigation question. 
1. From Activity A-> Activity B
2. on Activity B, click an action button to go back to Activity A (Activity B->Activity A)
3. on Activity A, click a cancel button to go back to Activity B (Activity A->Activity B).

I don't want to create Activity B twice. Is there a way to save Activity B at the second step? Thanks.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything big that gets initialized in B that is slowing the transition down? I'd just let the system do its thing, you can optimize state in an activity with `onSavedInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Comment: Yes Activity B loads a map. It's slow, can I don't want to load the same map twice if user chooses to cancel in the step 3.

Answer (score 0):

a quick and dirty way to do that might be to save a flag in a static class and check the flag to decide what to reinitialize in onCreate method